# biztalk esb toolkit newbie, after adding an itinerary step, should I restart biztalk host instance?

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.0

I am very new to esbtoolkit. If I change my current itinerary to include an extra step and a new subscription to subscribe to the new step, after deploy my orchestration, should I restart my biztalk host instance to make the step effective?

Is it realistic design I can archieve a true dynamic (in my opinion) esb, with no need to restart anything, just develp, deploy the new step (i.e. a subscribing orchestration) and everything just work smoothly?

thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to publish the itinerary update too. I am not sure if you can alter the itinerary and deploy the orchestration change separately without affecting the running processes.

Thanks,